# R barplot - highest value on top is hidden

Tags: r, bar-chart

Simple `barplot` with values on top of bars (I know it is silly - I was forced to add them :)). `text` works good, but value above highest frequency bar is hidden. I tried margins but it moves the whole plot instead of only the graph area. What can you suggest? Thanks!

```
x = c(28,1,4,17,2)
lbl = c("1","2","3","4+","tough guys\n(type in)")
bp = barplot(x,names.arg=lbl,main="Ctrl-C clicks",col="grey")
text(x = bp, y = x, label = x, pos = 3, cex = 0.8, col = "red",font=2)
```

Plot example:
[image]

Comment: use `bp = barplot(x,names.arg=lbl,main="Ctrl-C clicks",col="grey", ylim=c(0,30))`

Comment: `text(x = bp, y = x, label = x, pos = 3, cex = 0.8, col = "red",font=2, offset = -0.6)` maybe?

Comment: @RLave - offset moves them into the bars, which is not pretty (especially for low freq bars).

Comment: @G5W - that is a possible solution, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this by extending the `ylim`

```
bp = barplot(x,names.arg=lbl,main="Ctrl-C clicks",col="grey", ylim=c(0,30))
```

[image: Extended y range]

Comment: Thanks! This works. I wonder, though, where it hides. I also tried to move the main label - it's not behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
x = c(28,1,4,17,2)
lbl = c("1","2","3","4+","tough guys \n(type in)")
test <- data.frame(x, lbl)
bp = ggplot(test, aes(x=lbl, y= x))+
  geom_bar(color = "grey", stat="identity")+ ## set color of bars and use the value of the number in the cells.
  geom_text(aes(label= x), vjust = -1, color = "red")+
  ggtitle("Ctrl-C clicks")+
  theme_bw()+ ## give black and white theme
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),## adjust position of title
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),  ## suppress minor grid lines
        panel.grid.major=element_blank()  ##suppress major grid lines
        )+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,30)) ## set scale limits
bp
```

[image: Ctrl-C clicks]

Comment: Thanks. This gives me truncated number as well "out-of-the-box".

Comment: adjust the `vjust` number - negative for above the box, positive for inside. It's also possible to set the axis limits, like in the solution above. I can add the calls for colors and blank background etc. if you like.

Comment: it's already negative, like in your example. I copy-pasted your solution and it gives me "28" cut in half. Cannot attach pic to comments

Comment: what happens if you do `vjust = 0` apparently this should sit it on the line according to the justification section here:https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html

Comment: edited code to add extra customization you can play with if you need. I see that I left `vjust` as `-1`, it should read `-0.2` to match picture.